# How to update Mozilla Firefox web browser on 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in a safe, secure, reliable, efficient and easiest way?

Tags: 12.04, updates, firefox, 64-bit, mozilla

I'm using **64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS** on my machine.

Currently, I'm using **Mozilla Firefox 33.0(Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu canonical - 1.0)**

I'm not getting update option in menu Hrml->About Firefox but on when I visit few sites a pop-up appears at top of the browser window that asks me to update my current browser since it has become outdated.

But I don't know how to update my Firefox browser without Update link in Help->About Firefox menu.

Please provide me the best, effective and efficient solution on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: @DonaldBrown:No, but what will that do?

Comment: It will upgrade all out-dated software securely according to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, which contains Firefox and other system software. Edit: Also, if you could elaborate as to which sites this is an issue on, that would be helpful. Some sites these days just don't support Firefox for some silly reasons.

Comment: @DonaldBrown:Thanks for sharing the knowledge. I've run the commeand sudo apt-get upgrade in my machine's terminal. It's doing it's job. But tell me one more thing will this command upgrade my 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to the latest Ubuntu operating system version release?

Comment: no . it will update installed packages . you can use `sudo apt-get install firefox` for updating firefox alone.

Comment: @krizna : Ok, but if I want to upgrade to the latest stable release of Ubuntu Operating System Version what is the best possible way to do it?

Comment: @PHPLover A fresh install is the best possible way. Backup all your data beforehand!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You should find out what the latest packages available are, by first running:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then install the latest firefox:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

---

Or you could install the latest "everything" with:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Ubuntu should have an updater (don't remember exact name) that checks for and asks you about installing (or optionally automatically installs) newer packages/software. Is yours not running or set to keep quiet?

And there's also `apt-get dist-upgrade` that upgrades Ubuntu to a newer release, but it's traditionally less reliable than a fresh install.

Comment: Don't forget to `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` from time to time to get the most up-to-date software.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the Latest Firefox version from [here](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/)
2. Move this folder to /opt/
3. Open your terminal and type "./firefox"
4. Voila! Your New Firefox Version is running.
5. If you want to make this the default browser first go to /usr/bin
   and rename the previous version's Firefox executable to firefox-old
   and then move the new Firefox executable in /usr/bin

Answer (score 1):

Remove old version firefox from ubuntu using "softwarecenter", then again install firefox from "softwarecenter". It will automatically update firefox(only).